# Native Base Drawer not working

Tags: javascript, react-native

I tried to create drawer in my react native application. I've followed the example given but still not working for me to open drawer.

Below are my code :

```js
#drawer.js

export default class TalentDrawer extends Component {
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };
  render() {
    return (
       <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<Sidebar/>}
        panOpenMask={0.80}
        onClose={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
        onOpen={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}
        captureGestures="open"
        side="right"
        >
        <Dashboard openDrawer={this.openDrawer.bind(this)}/>
        </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
#dashboard.js
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button onPress={()=>this.props.openDrawer()}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I also follow instruction given for issues [Github](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/583) and still cannot get this drawer working for me. Anyone experience same issues with me? The example given at native-base website are not showing fully working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need some changes in your code,

Since dashboard.js does not deal with the state, we can change class to function.

## drawer.js

```js
export default class TalentDrawer extends Component {
  closeDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.close()
  };
  openDrawer = () => {
    this.drawer._root.open()
  };
  render() {
    return (
       <Drawer
        ref={(ref) => { this.drawer = ref; }}
        content={<Sidebar/>}
        panOpenMask={0.80}
        onClose={this.closeDrawer}
        onOpen={this.openDrawe}
        captureGestures="open"
        side="right"
        >
        <Dashboard openDrawer={this.openDrawer}/>
        </Drawer>
    );
  }
}
```

## dashboard.js

```js
const Dashboard = (props) => {
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1, alignItems:'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Button onPress={props.openDrawer}>
            <Text>Hello</Text>
            </Button>
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do

```
closeDrawer = () => {
  this.refs.drawer.close()
};
openDrawer = () => {
  this.refs.drawer.open()
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but i got an error said "undefined  is not an object (evaluating '_this.refs.drawer.close')

Comment: your problem is maybe styling problem can you add your sidebar also